# Better way to define a contract for a function with a lot of keyword arguments

Tags: function, racket, contract

Say I have a function that takes a lot of homogeneous keywords arguments:

```
(define (my-function #:arg1 arg1
                     #:arg2 arg2
                     ; etc.
                     #:argN argN) (do-something))
```

"Homogeneous" in the sense that they all fall under the same contract. Is there a better way of defining a contract for `my-function` without simply listing out all the arguments again, as in:

```
(-> #:arg1 my-arg/c
    #:arg2 my-arg/c
    ; etc.
    #:argN my-arg/c
    my-return/c)
```

I suppose one could write a macro for this, but is there an easier solution?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no better way, and macro is the best solution.